# SharePoint Client Object Model (COM) File Version Information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to get some basic file version information using the new SharePoint Client Object Model (COM) with SharePoint 2010. I have successfully loaded and queried for my ListItem, File, and FileVersionCollection like this:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(site)) {
   context.Load(context.Web);
   List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Docs");
   context.Load(docs);
   //query that returns the ListItems I want
   CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = ".."};

   ListItemCollection docItems = docs.GetItems(query);
   context.Load(docItems);
   context.ExecuteQuery();

   //load the FileVersionCollection
   foreach (ListItem listItem in docItems) {
      context.Load(listItem);
      context.Load(listItem.File);
      context.Load(listItem.File.Versions);
   }
   context.ExecuteQuery();
```

At this point, I can iterate through the `listItem.File.Versions` collection and get the `VersionLabel` and `Url`. However, I need to get the number of bytes of the version and the `FileVersion` object is lacking a `Size` or `Length` property.

I decided I could just read the version off the server and throw away the bytes (not efficient, I know, but it *should* work) like so:

```
foreach (FileVersion version in item.File.Versions) {
   FileInformation info = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, version.Url);

   long filesize = 0;

   Stream stream = info.Stream;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   int read = 0;
   while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0) {
      filesize += read;
   }

   //use the filesize
}
```

But every time I execute `File.OpenBinaryDirect` I get this error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: serverRelativeUrl
```

If I take the value of `version.Url` and put it into my browser, the file opens.

Any suggestions on how to get the file size? I would prefer not to open an HTTP stream and read the file, but if it comes to that, then I will.

BTW, I tried creating a new tag sharepoint-com but I don't have enough reputation. If someone with enough points thinks that tag is worthwhile, please create it :)

Answer (score 1):

`SPFile.Length` Gets the size of the file in bytes, excluding the size of any Web Parts that are used in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot access content of previous versions by [File.OpenBinaryDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537083.aspx). You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download it via HTTP/S directly instead.

```
Web web = ...;
FileVersion version = ...;
using (var input = new WebClient() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }) {
    string url = web.Url + "/" + version.Url;
    byte[] content = input.DownloadData(url);
}
```

See [this forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/2dd4706b-c779-4043-84d1-9234a5e436c8) about it.